# In java Multi-thread giving inconsistency value even-thought if use the synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

Here I am using `synchronized` for common counter variable for both threads `t1`, `t2` but even though counter value getting as inconsistency, please can any one explain why it's giving results like this and give a solution.

```java
public class Sync {
    public static int counter = 0;

    private static synchronized void increment() {
        ++counter;
    }

    public static void process() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    increment();
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    increment();
            }

        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        process();
        System.out.println("counter is:: " + counter);
    }
}
```

It should give counter value as 2000.

Comment: You start your threads, but you do not wait for them to complete. If you want to see 2000, then you should call join on both threads

Comment: The call to `process()` does not wait for the threads to complete. Hence, the println will not necessarily give you the final couter value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your Main thread does not wait for the other threads to finish. And it prints the result while other threads are still incrementing the counter.

Use `Thread.join()` to fix it:

```java
t1.join();
t2.join();
```